# $R$ a domain subset of a field $K$. $I\trianglelefteq R$, show $I$ is a projective $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

> Let $R$ be a domain, $K$ a field and $R\subseteq K$. Let $I\trianglelefteq R$. Now $k_1,\ldots, k_n\in K$ are elements such that $k_iI\subseteq R$ forall $i=1,\ldots,n$. Now suppose there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in I$ such that $a_1k_1+\ldots +a_nk_n=1$.
>
> 1. Show $I=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$
> 2. Show that $I$ is a projective $R$-module

I've managed to prove 1.  But I don't find a way to show 2. I think I need to write $R$ as a direct summand: $R\cong I\oplus B$ for a certain $B\leq R$ (as a $R$-submodule). My first idea was to try something like $B=R\setminus I$ however this does not work, since $1\in B$ which would imply $B=R$ (?)

What would be a good way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi \colon R^{n} \to I$ be the surjective morphism of $R$-modules given by $\varphi(r_{1}, \ldots, r_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_{i}a_{i}$. We have a short exact sequence of $R$-modules

$$0 \to \ker(\varphi) \to R^{n} \to I \to 0.$$

To show that $I$ is projective, it is enough to show that this exact sequence is split, whence $R^{n} \cong I \oplus \ker(\varphi)$. Indeed, consider the morphism of $R$-modules $\rho\colon I \to R^{n}$ given by $x \mapsto (k_{1}x, \ldots, k_{n}x)$. Then

$$(\varphi \circ \rho)(x) = \varphi(k_{1}x, \ldots, k_{n}x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}k_{i}x = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}k_{i}\right)x = 1 \cdot x = x$$

and therefore $\varphi \circ \rho = Id_{I}$, as desired.

Comment: Then this implies $R^n = \mathrm{ker}(\phi) \oplus \mathrm{im}(\rho)$ and since $\rho$ is injective $\mathrm{im}(\rho)\cong I$. Which implies $I$ to be a projective module. Am I right that the fact that $K$ is a field is begin used in this injectivity? $\rho(x)=\rho(y)$ then $k_i\cdot x=k_i \cdot y \Rightarrow x=y$?

Comment: @dietervdf: well, $\rho$ has a left inverse, so it is necessarily injective, but your argument works as well.

Comment: Of course :) I don't really see where the fact that $K$ is a field is being used.. Why should the inverses of $k_i$ exist? Any ideas?

Comment: @dietervdf: that's a reasonable question, one I'm afraid I don't have a great answer to. One silly observation: if there elements $k_{i}$ were in $R$, then $I$ would just be the unit ideal, hence trivially projective. I think $K$ is just a natural enlargement of $R$ where the conditions on the elements $k_{1}, \ldots, k_{n}$ don't make $I$ an uninteresting ideal of $R$.